# visual C++ program how to make it interact with other program

Tags: c++, qt

I have question how to make a program and then run it on 2 different computers, and then I'd like to somehow connect them together, so they could interact with each other. For example i type some text in program on my computer, and then text would show up on other computer.
Can you point me to some literature, or what should i look at to do something like this.

Comment: Networking or magic...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of connecting two computers over a socket.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html

Some related terms you should get to know are: TCP, UDP, IP, Socket, Port, IP Address

Qt makes most of the work of getting them talking to each other pretty simple.

Btw, at the time of writing, Qt 5.2 is the most up to date one to get.

Hope that helps.